# How to get a C-string out of a string that contains \0 without losing the \0

Tags: c++, null-terminated

I currently have a pretty huge string. I NEED to convert it into a C-string (char*), because the function I want to use only take C-string in parameter.

My problem here is that any thing I tried made the final C-string wayyy smaller then the original string, because my string contains many \0. Those \0 are essential, so I can't simply remove them :(...

I tried various way to do so, but the most common were :

```
myString.c_str();
myString.data();
```

Unfortunately the C-string was always only the content of the original string that was before the first \0.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot create a C-string which contains `'\0'` characters, because a C-string is, by definition, a sequence of characters terminated by `'\0'` (also called a "zero-terminated string"), so the first `'\0'` in the sequence ends the string.

However, there are interfaces that take a a pointer to the first character *and* the length of the character sequence. These might be able to deal with character sequences including `'\0'`.

Watch out for `myString.data()`, because this returns a pointer to a character sequence that might not be zero-terminated, while `mystring.c_str()` always returns a zero-terminated C-string.

Comment: Oh well... thanks for the answer, this leave me with another problematic. I'll post a new question.

Comment: @Zwik: I was just about to post a comment requesting you to explain _what_ you want to achieve, instead of asking for the means to achieve it _this way_. `:)`

Comment: i'll be posting it tonight, i'll link it here ;)

Comment: @Zwik: It's almost midnight here. I won't see it until tomorrow morning. `:)`

Comment: @sbi: Thanks for pointing out the difference between the data() and c_str() methods -- I've been curious about that myself for some time.

Comment: @pr1268: I think all `std::string` implementations I ave looked at store their data as a zero-terminated string anyway and both `data()` and `c_str()` just return a pointer to that internal storage, but it's not guaranteed and should not be relied on. (Just a few years ago we considered COW string implementations for granted, too, and see how that has changed dramatically.)

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. The null is the end of a null terminated string. If you take a look at your character buffer (use `&myString[0]`), you'll see that the NULLs are still there. However, no C functions are going to interpret those NULLs correctly because NULL is not a valid value in the middle of a string in C.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `myString` has probably been truncated at construction/assignment time. You can try `std::basic_string::assign` which takes two iterators as arguments or simply use `std::vector <char>`, the latter being more usual in your use case.
And your API taking that C string must actually support taking a char pointer together with a length.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused, but:

```
string x("abc");
if (x.c_str()[3] == '\0')
{ cout << "there it is" << endl; }
```

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: I think the OP is referring to cases where you'd have things like `"ab\0c\0def\0g"`. That's perfectly fine in a `std::string`, but not in a null terminated character array.

Comment: @Billy well, in that case he should either use `vector<string>` or simply `vector<char>`

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Why? `std::string` handles the nulls just fine.

Comment: @Billy Well this question pretty much proves that it doesn't. :-D The fact, that string doesn't break horribly if a `\0` is inserted is a different story.

Comment: yeah but eh function that I need to use only takes char* as params

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: `std::string` handles the nulls just fine. It's the other functions where Zwik want's to pass the `char *` that cannot handle the nulls. Using a `vector<char>` wouldn't solve the problem here.

Comment: @Billy I just tested it and string actually breaks on GCC if the string contains '\0' characters.

Comment: @Billy Sorry, the standard is actually more liberal about string then I thought.

Answer (score 0):

This may not meet your needs, you did say 'Those \0 are essential', but how about escaping or replacing the '\0' chars?

Would one of these ideas work?

1. replace the '\0' chars with a '\t' (tab char, decimal 9).
2. replace the '\0' with some rarely used char value like decimal 1, or decimal 255.
3. Create an escape code, say by replacing each '\0' char with a coded substring, (like octal as in "\000").  (Be sure to replace any original '\' with a coded value as well (like "\134")).